# Comment prononcer la liaison dans « le premier étage » ?

Tags: prononciation, liaisons

Je crois qu’il faut faire la liaison : *le premier‿étage*.

Alors, la lettre « r » se prononce, mais comment faut-il prononcer « premier » ?

Est-ce qu’on retient la prononciation masculine : [pʁə.mje] ?

Ou ça change vers la prononciation féminine : [pʁə.mjɛʁ] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les deux sont possibles. Cela dépend du locuteur, des sons environnants, voire de son humeur du moment.

L'article de [Wikipédia en français](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais#En_pratique_%3a_technique_de_lecture_et_r.C3.A9alisation_des_liaisons) donne justement un exemple avec l'adjectif *premier* : « premier enfant » [pʁə.mj**ɛ**.ʁ‿ ɑ̃.fɑ̃], et [l'article en anglais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_%28French%29#Realization_of_liaison) donne carrément « premier étage » [pʁə.mj**ɛ**.ʁ‿e.taʒ]. Cela dit, ces articles sont incomplets. La transformation du [e] en [ɛ.ʁ] n'est pas systématique, et ne se fait que pour les adjectifs. Je pense que c'est l'existence de la forme féminine en [-ɛʁ] qui valide la transformation de la voyelle.

Après un nom ou un verbe, on conserve toujours la voyelle [e] : « un parler étrange » [œ̃.paʁ.le.ʁ‿etr ɑ̃ʒ] (en fait, on ne ferait souvent pas la liaison), « sortons marcher un peu » [sɔʁ.tɔ̃.maʁ.ʃeʁ‿œ̃.pø] (on ne fait la liaison que dans la langue soutenue).

On trouve une transformation analogue avec les adjectifs qui se terminent par la voyelle nasale [ɔ̃] (et peut-être d'autres ? il ne me vient pas d'exemple à l'esprit) avec un N final : « bon appétit » [b**ɔ**.n‿a.pe.ti]. Dans ce cas aussi, la voyelle ne change que dans les adjectifs : « mon enfant » [mɔ̃.n‿ ɑ̃.fɑ̃], « un enfant » [œ̃.n‿ ɑ̃.fɑ̃].

Comment: Dans « sortons marcher un peu » ça me semble difficile de ne pas faire la liaison.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, une enquête de terrain du type PFC s'impose. Dans leurs résultats, les liaisons potentielles après verbes à l'infinitif étaient réalisées dans 5% des cas. http://www.projet-pfc.net/pfc-recherche/liaisonsn.html

Answer (score 1):

Il faut prononcer exactement comme "premier Rétage".

Le féminin est différent : on prononce comme "*premiaire*".

Du moins à Paris, on a tendance à prononcer premier comme "*promier*", ou "*preumier*". Et au Canada et en Belgique, "première" est plus proche de "premiére".

Comment: Non à Paris on prononce le premier e de premier comme le *e* de le (et donc pas comme *eu* de meule).

Comment: J'ai écrit "on a tendance" pour ne pas préciser le quartier, et les différences sont sensibles selon l'arrondissement et le niveau d'études.

Comment: Je ne vois qu'un liftier/garçon d'ascenseur pour le prononcer ainsi.

Comment: @Knu Assez méprisant de désigner une profession honorable d'un mot franglais ou sexiste. Je suppose que vous fréquentez plus le Quartier Latin que Belleville ou Ménilmontant (en ne pensant qu'aux habitants Français "de souche", bien entendu, qui habitent un cinquième sans ascenseur, sur cour), et encore moins le Berry. A tel point qu'en langage enfantin, le "preu" (prononcé exactement comme "preux", mais sans aucun rapport étymologique) désigne le premier à jouer une partie. Et pourquoi pas - à l'époque classique on prononçait "prémier", accent gardé au Québec.

Comment: Je ne donne juste que mon avis ; qui semble d'ailleurs être partagé. Votre remarque désobligeante sur ma soi-disant situation m'a fait bien rire par contre.

Comment: @MarkThorin "promier"? Jamais entendu prononcé comme ça, ni à Paris, ni ailleurs en France ou dans un pays francophone... A limite, "prôôômier", pour donner une touche théâtrale, et dans un contexte extrêmement précis.

Comment: La prononciation « pre-miè-ré-tage » est possible, et même je crois la plus courante.

Answer (score 1):

Nous avons un ascenseur parlant avec une voix de femme (à Paris) qui prononce "première étage". Personnellement je préfère "premier rétage". Qui me semble plus correct contrairement à ce que dit wiki.